# 1.6.1.24 update to 1.7.7.4 database schema error

Tags: php, prestashop, mamp, prestashop-1.7, php-7.1

I am sandbox upgrading a copy of my live Prestashop website in MAMP (free) following the iteration:

- my website is a 1.6.1.3
- I perform an update of the stated 1.6.1.3 to a 1.6.1.24 with a 1-click update and everything goes smooth, then I change MAMP from PHP 5.6.40 to 7.1.33 while uninstalling and deleting (in this order) all non-native modules and themes except reviews and pay plug
- I fresh install, in a different htdocs directory and in a different database, a 1.6.1.24 and I copy inside modules reviews and pay plug,  the img folder and the setting file
- I delete the 1.6.1.3 updated to 1.6.1.24 directory and the fresh install 1.6.1.24 database and connect the 1.6.1.24 fresh install to the  1.6.1.3 updated to 1.6.1.24 database and I modify the fresh install 1.6.1.24 directory to match the updated one that has been deleted
- So I have a fresh install of PrestaShop connected to my previous historical complete database
- In all of this process I kept non-native module and overrides deactivated and performed multiple database checkout with module Prestashop cleaner 1.8 and reverted to the official theme, so a very "vanilla" situation.

At this point, I tested all the functions of the local website I find myself with and everything seems to go fine, no errors while using debug mode, so I feel comfortable in using the 1-click module to update to PS 1.7.7.4.

- I put the zip in the download folder and proceed with the update.  Everything goes smooth in the files update (all green), but when the process goes to the database, I find myself with an error and a barely accessible back office, with front-office, and back-office orders, customers, and setting inaccessible due to too many redirects.

Here are the database update situation and errors:

```
Updating database schema...

Executing: CREATE TABLE ps_translation (id_translation INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, id_lang INT NOT NULL, `key` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_bin, translation TEXT NOT NULL, domain VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, theme VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL, INDEX IDX_ADEBEB36BA299860 (id_lang), INDEX `key` (domain), PRIMARY KEY(id_translation)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

Executing: CREATE TABLE ps_module_history (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, id_employee INT NOT NULL, id_module INT NOT NULL, date_add DATETIME NOT NULL, date_upd DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

Executing: CREATE TABLE ps_admin_filter (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, employee INT NOT NULL, shop INT NOT NULL, controller VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, action VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, filter LONGTEXT NOT NULL, filter_id VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX admin_filter_search_id_idx (employee, shop, controller, action, filter_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

Executing: DROP INDEX lang_iso_code ON ps_lang

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_lang CHANGE active active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , CHANGE iso_code iso_code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, CHANGE language_code language_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, CHANGE date_format_lite date_format_lite VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y-m-d' , CHANGE date_format_full date_format_full VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , CHANGE is_rtl is_rtl TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Executing: CREATE INDEX IDX_2F43BFC7BA299860 ON ps_lang_shop (id_lang)

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_lang_shop RENAME INDEX id_shop TO IDX_2F43BFC7274A50A0

Executing: DROP INDEX id_lang ON ps_attribute_lang

Executing: CREATE INDEX IDX_3ABE46A77A4F53DC ON ps_attribute_lang (id_attribute)

Executing: CREATE INDEX IDX_3ABE46A7BA299860 ON ps_attribute_lang (id_lang)

Executing: DROP INDEX deleted ON ps_shop_group

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_shop_group CHANGE active active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' , CHANGE deleted deleted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Executing: DROP INDEX id_parent ON ps_tab

Executing: DROP INDEX class_name ON ps_tab

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_tab ADD route_name VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE position position INT NOT NULL, CHANGE active active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' , CHANGE hide_host_mode hide_host_mode TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , CHANGE icon icon VARCHAR(32) DEFAULT ''

Executing: DROP INDEX id_shop_group ON ps_shop

Executing: DROP INDEX id_category ON ps_shop

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_shop CHANGE id_category id_category INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' , CHANGE theme_name theme_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CHANGE active active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' , CHANGE deleted deleted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

Executing: CREATE INDEX IDX_CBDFBB9EF5C9E40 ON ps_shop (id_shop_group)

Executing: ALTER TABLE ps_attribute CHANGE color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, CHANGE position INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

01:24:42 ERROR [console] Error thrown while running command "prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign --env=prod". Message: "An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE ps_attribute CHANGE color color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, CHANGE position position INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ':

SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'color' at row 20" ["exception" => Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException { …},"command" => "prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign --env=prod","message" => """ An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE ps_attribute CHANGE color color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, CHANGE position position INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ':\n \n SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'color' at row 20 """]

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 106:


An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE ps_attribute CHANGE colo

r color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, CHANGE position INT NOT NULL DEFAULT

'0' ':


SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'color' at row 20


In PDOConnection.php line 90:


SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'color' at row 20


In PDOConnection.php line 88:


SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'color' at row 20


prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--id_shop [ID_SHOP]] [--id_shop_group [ID_SHOP_GROUP]] [--]
```

Do you have any solution to suggest?
How do I address which tables are provoking the issue in order to correct them before proceeding with the 1.7.7.4 update?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions provided.

The following are the specifications of MAMP at the time of the error:
PHP: 7.1.33

```
max_execution_time30000

max_file_uploads20

max_input_nesting_level64

max_input_time60000

max_input_vars10000

memory_limit1024M

post_max_size256M
```

Web server: Apache

Comment: It means exactly what it says. You're running `ALTER TABLE ps_attribute CHANGE color color VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL` and a few rows have values in the column that are longer than 32 characters.

Comment: [SOLVED] Thanks! I found I field with 35 characters in it. Thanks a lot for pointing me on the right direction!

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the titles here. If you found your own answer you can post and accept it, or delete the question

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining me the dynamics of this community but I could not see the accept answer button and that is why I implemented the solved tag. Unfortunately someone moderated my question as a duplicate linking it to a completely different error and matter and I think this may preclude my solution to of help for someone with my same issue.